# Elasticsearch Wildcard query Result Hits Also Change

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version: 7.10.2
Currently, I met a strange issue about wildcard queries with wildcard type in the new version.
I used the DSL query as follows

```
{"_source":"brand_name","query":{"wildcard":{"brand_name":{"value":"*wUg*"}}},"sort":[{"shop_id":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

Hit Result Response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c8kr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ees4.png)

But the same query hits total always change for each time, I read the official documents and didn't find any answers. So Is any master can help to check this issue?
Index Settings

```
{
  "wildcard_query_1000w" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "3",
        "provided_name" : "wildcard_query_1000w",
        "creation_date" : "1614589156629",
        "analysis" : {
          "normalizer" : {
            "lowerasciinormalizer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "type" : "custom"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "my_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "SL4M3NLySB6f0MPVhM-v7A",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7100299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index Mapping

```
{
  "wildcard_query_1000w" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
          "string" : {
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "normalizer" : "lowerasciinormalizer",
              "type" : "wildcard"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties" : {
        "brand_name" : {
          "type" : "wildcard"
        },
        "entity_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "shop_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "ssp_doc_ts" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "status" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "toc" : {
          "properties" : {
            "loyalty" : {
              "properties" : {
                "tier" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show several different responses you get?

Comment: Hi Val, I pasted the pictures in the questions. after Hit Result Response, could you see that?

Comment: Yes, very puzzling indeed

Comment: Also just wanted to make sure that you were aware that the `lowerasciinormalizer` was not being used by the `brand_name` field

Comment: Could I know what's the difference between including ```lowerasciinormalizer``` and not including ```lowerasciinormalizer```

Comment: I have no idea what your intent is with that normalizer, I'm just pointing at the fact that as it stands (given your settings and mappings), that normalizer is not applied on the `brand_name` field if this is what you expect

Comment: Oh I C, Actually I just wanna search the result case insentitive